# XSLT-1.0 array disable sorting

Tags: arrays, xslt-1.0

I have many similar operations, for example, check that one tag is sum of two other tags.
To write it once, I do next:

```
    <xsl:variable name="psumArray" select="//AAA/SUM1 | //AAA/SUM2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="psummandArray1" select="//AAA/A1 | //AAA/A2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="psummandArray2" select="//AAA/B1 | //AAA/B2"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$psumArray">
        <xsl:variable name="temppos" select="position()"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=" format-number((text()), '#.##') != format-number(number($psummandArray1[$temppos]/text()) + number($psummandArray2[$temppos]/text())), '#.##')">
            <ERROR>error!</ERROR>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

And I can put to my array variables any number of "selects". But I found that each array sorts it's result by name. And order of members in array is not defined by sequence that I wrote, but defined by select text comparation.

I.e.:

```
<xsl:variable name="psummandArray2" select="//AAA/B3 | //AAA/B2"/>
```

Will become as:

```
<xsl:variable name="psummandArray2" select="//AAA/B2 | //AAA/B3"/>
```

After sorting.
How to avoid it? Or how to achieve what I want to another way, if that way is not the best?

UPD:
Imput XML is similar to:

```
<XML>
    <A1>50</A1>
    <A2>20</A2>
    <A3>70</A3>
    <A4>90</A4>
    <A5>5</A5>
    <A6>45</A6>
    <A7>35</A7>
    <A8>25</A8>
    <A9>80</A9>
    <A10>110</A10>
    <A11>100</A11>
    <A12>30</A12>
    <A13>70</A13>
    ...
    <A120>33</A120>
</XML>
```

And there exists rules, such as:

```
A3 = A6 + A8 
A13 = A1 + A2
```

and etc. More then hundred rules. I have to write XSLT that would check all those rules, and if rule is wrong at some nodes, I have to print `<ERROR>Error!</ERROR>`

The best I think is to write XSLT, where I need just to add name of sum node and names of summand nodes.

That is why I wrote xslt as above, to check it. And now I was going just to put all rules to arrays. And then I found it sorts arrays, breaking my plans :-)

Comment: There are no arrays in XML/XSL. What you have is node-sets. And if you don't sort them otherwise, they will be processed in document order (not by name, as you think). -- P.S. Please indicate (always!) if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I would consider to use an approach like the one used to implement Schematron, there is a language to write the rules and then there is a stylesheet that processes a rules document to generate the corresponding XSLT stylesheet checking the rules and outputting an errors or assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have ~100 tasks to check if one node is a sum of two another nodes.
>   And I don't want to write comparation 100 times

Well, you have to write it out at least once, since it doesn't seem to follow any kind of logic that could be automated. Here's one way you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/XML">
    <xsl:variable name="tests">
        <xsl:call-template name="test-sum">
            <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="A3"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="summands" select="A6 | A8"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
        <xsl:call-template name="test-sum">
            <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="A13"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="summands" select="A1 | A2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
        <!-- ... -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="contains($tests, 'error')">
        <ERROR>Error!</ERROR>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="test-sum">
    <xsl:param name="sum"/>
    <xsl:param name="summands"/>
    <xsl:if test="$sum!=sum($summands)">
        <xsl:text>error</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you could express your rules **as XML** - either in an external document, or in the stylesheet itself, then apply a template to that.

Comment: Now I need to have output depending on errors was met (for A3 = A6 + A8 error text should be: "abrakadabra", for A13 = A1 + A2 it should be "Winter is coming"), and if there was 5 errors - I have to output different text 5 times.
I think to add additional parameter to template "test-sum" - with that text, give it there with other parameters. And then somehow print it.

Comment: You could (1) pass the error message as an additional parameter and (2) output the results directly - preferably (IMHO) as XML - without going through a variable first.

Comment: If I write instead of "error" something like "<ERROR><CODE>30</CODE><TEXT><xsl:value-of select="$output-text"/></TEXT></ERROR>", it prints text, but not prints tags. I wonder why :-(

Comment: Why? Because you are outputting the (text) value of a variable. Why do you need the variable at all?

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2.0 and an XSLT 2.0 processor you can use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="psumArray" select="//AAA/SUM1 , //AAA/SUM2"/>` to get a sequence of `SUM1` elements followed by `SUM2` elements.

Comment: Wow, thank you, but I afraid I use XSLT 1.0, what should I do then?

Comment: @Arkady Perhaps you should use a named template; it's difficult to see what the "savings" are without seeing an example input and understanding the extent of the task.

Comment: @Arkady, I agree with Michael that it is hard to tell you how to solve that problem without seeing a descriptive input sample and the result you want for that sample. You might want to edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: I have ~100 tasks to check if one node is a sum of two another nodes. And I don't want to write comparation 100 times, that is why I thought about creating arrays. Now will change question to make it more clear.